# how to extract/import text from Table data which is seperated by two pipes

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How do I extract/import text from Table data which is separated by two pipes?

I use

```
=importhtml(A1, "table",7)
```

`A1` is `https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=tsla`, the output is the text between the two pipes.

```
TSLA[NASD]      
*Tesla, Inc.*       
Consumer Cyclical | Auto Manufacturers | USA
```

**How do I extract only "Auto Manufacturers"?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

One could also have the same result (as in the below original answer) without even having to import the table to a different cell.

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(INDEX(TRANSPOSE(IMPORTHTML(A1, "table",7)),,3),"| (.*) |")
```

[image]

Or even use just the following formula, omit all of the reference cells and import the final `Auto Manufacturers` directly.

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(INDEX(TRANSPOSE(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=tsla", "table",7)),,3),"\| (.*) \|")
```

---

**Original answer**

Please try the following formula

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A5,"\| (.*) \|")
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`REGEXEXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)
- [`INDEX`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242)
- [`TRANSPOSE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262)
- [`IMPORTHTML`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339)

Comment: Hi Marikamitos, thank you all options worked, I prefer option 1. One last question before we close this, what does the  ,,3 mean.?  ie does this mean third item in row 3 ? I thought if you have removed the pipes it would be item 2.

Comment: *"what does the ,,3 mean.?"*. It means the 3rd column. Try *"peeling"* the formula from inside out to understand how it works. Also. *"...before we close this"* you could probably accept and upvote the answer :)

Comment: Hi Marikamitsos, I have accpted your answer and upvoted as requested. Thanks for all your help with this comment.